# Assigning a flag to a new column 'A' when continuously 5 cells value of existing column 'B' is blank of a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to assign flag to a new column based on the cell values of other existing column.

Example:
if continuously 5 cell values of a column is blank then new column will have the flag as 'text-1' otherwise 'text-2'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column B':['a','bc','d','','','ef','df','','','','','','fg']})
df['Column A'] = np.where(df['Column B'].groupby((df['Column B'] != df['Column B'].shift()).cumsum()).transform(len) >= 5,'text-1','text-2')

   Column B Column A
0         a   text-2
1        bc   text-2
2         d   text-2
3             text-2
4             text-2
5        ef   text-2
6        df   text-2
7             text-1
8             text-1
9             text-1
10            text-1
11            text-1
12       fg   text-2
```